# Python Tkinter Error When Using MatPlotLib

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Can someone help me with this error message. I am using MatPlotLib to graph something, but I get the following error message when I call the function to graph it. [Tkinter Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwAbx.png)

```
Use one of following commands are :: --
'UPLOAD' to upload a file
'DOWNLOAD' to download a file
'DELETE' to delete a file
'DIR' to view the current directories
DOWNLOAD
enter the name of the file to download!!!
break.txt
file opened
file close()
time:  start =  0  end =  1587306325.2672875
time:  transfer_time =  1587306325267.287
file downloaded and graph is shown below!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file_client.py", line 117, in <module>
    plot_graph(result)
  File "file_client.py", line 81, in plot_graph
    plt.scatter(list(time_dict.keys()), list(time_dict.values()))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3364, in scatter
    ax = gca()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 962, in gca
    return gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 592, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 539, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 171, in new_figure_                                                                                                manager
    return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 1049, in n                                                                                                ew_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk(className="matplotlib")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2023, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useT                                                                                                k, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Comment: Add error message as text

Comment: Are you running the application in an environment without graphical desktop environment, like ssh or online?

Comment: @acw1668 I am running it in putty.

Comment: Then most likely you are using SSH.  Enable X11 forwarding in PuTTY and run a X server if your host is Windows.